# I have a confusion in knowing when to use $P(A∩B$) and $P(A\backslash B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I often stumble upon problems which requires me to take a hard decision on what should I apply in problems. I really want to know the diffrence between $p(A\cap B)$ and $p(A\mid B)$ in a specific way(actual mathematical meaning is clear) but.. let me explain by example.

Consider an exam where $P(E_k)$ is the prob that exactly $k$ people pass the exam so consider a situation in which you defien an event $A$ such that $P(A)=$ prob that you select one student and that student has passed the exam.

So if I ask you what's the prob that only one student has passed the exam. What will you say $P(E_1\cap A)=p(E_1)P(A\mid E_1)$ or $P(E_1\mid A)$?

Kindly help me with this thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: When you wrote $P(A/B)$, did you mean $P(A\mid B)$?

Comment: Yes precisely..

Comment: I changed it thanks for pointing out

Comment: Doing two things together is not the same as doing one thing after the other.

Comment: Something seems odd about the formulation of the problem. You define $P(E_k)$ to be the probability that exactly $k$ people pass, and then you ask the probability of only one student passing, which by definition would be $P(E_1)$. Maybe you should add the word "specific" to underline that you want to know the probability of a specific student passing and not an arbitrary student (if that is what you are asking).

Comment: Also the event $A$ is a bit ambiguous. Should it be the probability of a specific person passing or the probability of a randomly chosen student to have passed?

Comment: @Leander , No what I meant was that event A is the event that the student X selected at random passes the examination

Comment: @Leander I have defined the event $E_k$ that exactly k students pass the exam and P(A) is probability that randomly if you choose a student you find that he passed the exam. In other words A: a student X is randomly selected passes the exam

Comment: That clarifies what $E_k$ and $A$ mean. Note that if we know that exactly one person passed, then the probability of choosing that person at random would be $\frac{1}{N}$ where $N$ is the number of people. Therefore $P(A \: | \: E_1) = \frac{1}{N}$ and $P(A\cap E_1) = \frac{P(E_1)}{N}$. It is however still unclear to me, what you are trying to compute. $P(A\cap E_1)$ would be "the probability of choosing one student at random and that this student is the only one who passes the exam".

Comment: So the question is that what is the probability that a student X selected at random is the only one who passes the exam. this question I took from a self practice book on probability.The author  has used bayes rule. According to him probability of the above mentioned happening is P($E_1$/A) which got me confused as I was using P($E_1$∩A) I couldn't find how to correct my mistake and why I was making it as deciding between these 2 was a problem for me

Comment: This is extremely hard to follow.  The event $A$ seems to be irrelevant.  If the question is, as you write, "what's the prob that only one student has passed the exam" the answer is obviously $P(E_1)$, by definition.  Of course, this is not the same as $P(E_1\cap A)$ despite your assertion.

Comment: In my experience, ambiguity starts with vague language.  If you phrase a situation informally and imprecisely, then of course it will be difficult to translate it into mathematical formalism.  Just sort out out clearly and explicitly what it is you are asking and the formalism will follow naturally.

Comment: First of all thankyou for mentaining patience with me as I am still on path of applying probability correctly. Secondly I think it will be better if you saw the complete question. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1BSly_UInkF2SyAcvQyKwpS9QaM1Zp7j0

Comment: That link doesn't appear to work.  In any case, don't attach critical information via links.  Just type the question verbatim into your post.

Comment: Q88 is my doubt

Comment: According to my approach and should be d opt the p(E and A) one.

Comment: Question $88$ is asking :  "Suppose $P(E_k)$ is a constant, independent of $k$.  Suppose further that we have selected a student at random and discovered that this particular student did in fact pass the course.  What, then, is the probability that this particular student is the only student to have passed the course?"  It's a Bayes Theoprem problem.

Comment: Yeah I got it thanks for the help! how did you add that large bit of information yourself ? I struggle at that part ! Any suggestions?

Comment: The first step is to sort out what constant $P(E_k)$ must be.  The second step is to work out the probability that a randomly selected student is discovered to have passed the exam.

Comment: Yeah I did the 1st step  but I coulnt think of how you did the step of thinking about Bayes theorm . What I thought was  that what is the probability that only one student passed and you found that student randomly ie p(E and A)

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  What constant must $P(E_k)$ be?

Comment: C=1/n+1 is the req

Comment: As the sum of all p(Ek) must be 1 as they all constitute exaustive events

Comment: Good.  So now, you have to solve question $87$.  To do it, note that we must be in one of the (mutually exclusive) events $E_k$...just sum over those cases.  That is to say, $P(A)=\sum_{k=0}^nP(E_k)\times P(E_k\cap A)$.

Comment: I can apply total probability theorm in q 87. Yeah exactly and sir one last thing

Comment: So, do that. $\quad$

Comment: How did you not think of the question like  I mentioned in the above comment ". What I thought was that what is the probability that only one student passed and you found that student randomly ie p(E and A

Comment: What led you to think of the situation like this

Comment: Just ignore the formalism and think about what the question means.  You are given the (somewhat unlikely) information that all the events $E_k$ are equally probable.  Furthermore you are given the results of an experiment...namely that a randomly selected student passed.  That, of course, is evidence that a lot of students passed.  Not proof, of course...it is possible that you just happened to pick the only one who passed.  But it is more likely that lots of them passed.  Bayes let;s you sort out the details.

Comment: Oh okay so we had to ourselves think that it was given that a lot of then passed ( which is kind of obvious)( I don't know why I missed that)am I undestanding it correclty? I think the part "given that a passed the exam " is what we had to think ourselbes

Comment: No...   A priori we are told that it is equally likely that no students passed or that they all passed (or any number in between).  But selecting a student gives us new evidence.  We know for certain, for example, that we are not in the event $E_0$.  If nobody passed, then our randomly selected student can't have passed.  $E_1$ is still possible, but it is looking improbable...if only one student passed, it's not likely that we chose them at random.  Bayes' Theorem lets us incorporate this information into new estimates for the probabilities.

Comment: Oh so it lets us re acess our pre imposed probabilities assigned to original probability

Comment: Yes, that's what Bayes' does.  Like I say, before we did the experiment, we thought that $P(E_0)$ was $\frac 1{n+1}$.  Having done the experiment, we know believe it is $0$.  More precisely, we have $P(E_0\,|\,A)=0$.  It is worth working out $P(E_k\,|\,A)$ for all $k$, even though you are only asked about $k=1$.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: So you mean we can change the exisiting probabilites on the basis of doing new experiments which makes our overall knowledge of prediction better for eg in this we can recalculate the overall probabilty of all the Eks by using bays over and over again because P(Ek/A) will be the new Ek every time till the change becomes very low. Is that the essence of Bayes therom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $P(A \mid B)$ when $B$ is something given, i.e., read $P(A\mid B)$ as $\textit{probability of A given B}$.

Use $P(A \cap B)$ when both $A$ and $B$ have to happen but nothing is given.

Let $F_k$ be the probability that at least $k$ students pass the exam

1. What is the probability of $10$ students passing the exam if we know that $9$ students passed the exam? $P(F_{10} \mid F_9) = P(F_{10}\cap F_9) / P(F_9) =  P(F_{10}) / P(F_9)$.
2. What is the probability of $10$ students passing the exam and $9$ students passing the exam? $P(F_{10} \cap F_9) = P(F_{10})$

The second probability is always lower since the event that is already given in the first case might not happen in the second case.

Comment: If $E_k$ is the event that exactly $k$ people pass, then wouldn't we have $E_k \cap E_j = \emptyset$ for $k\neq j$ ?

Comment: @Antoine Yeah so sir can you please confirm that in the type of example that I gave, I will give my ans (P(E1/A) right? .Because A was the probability that a random student X selected passes the exam . I think it's understood by the example problem, that I said that the student has passed and we are finding the prob that he/she is the only one,passed given that he has passed.     kindly confirm sir if I have understood this correctly.

Comment: @Leander Tilsted yes I think you are correct,

Comment: As others have remarked, this is wrong.  Since $E_k$ is the event "*exactly* $k$ people have passed", we have $E_i\cap E_j=\emptyset$ when $i\neq j$.

Comment: You are right. Hava changed to $F_k$ :)

Comment: @RadacRor I think that the answer to your question is $P(A) = \sum_{k = 0}^n P(A \cap E_k)$, since $A$ is "a disjunctive union" of events $A\cap E_k$.

Comment: Yes you are correct